# Item numbers in Paypal order - why is it adding numbers to item_number?

Tags: paypal

I just added some more Buy Now buttons to my site - single items per button, and have noticed that instead of item_number in my IPN, it says item_number1 (plus other fields in the IPN are having a 1 added), even though I haven't check any multiple item or price boxes when setting up the button.

The button set up is the same as my other Buy Now buttons, which are still sending item_number as I want.

Is there another reason the other Buy Now buttons are adding a 1 to certain fields?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - it was because I'd made it a Shopping Cart button instead of a Buy Now one.